# Can Supertest help me verify that my API returns a callback/jsonp function?

Tags: node.js, callback, jsonp, mocha.js, supertest

In the spirit of test-driven development, I'm trying to find a way to verify that my API can return results wrapped in a callback function when requested to do so.  Like this:

```
GET http://example.com/api/resource/?callback=handleThis

handleThis( {"foo": "bar"} );
```

I'm using mocha & supertest.  Short of turning the response variable into a string and comparing that to a reference string, is there any other clever way to verify that the test suite is receiving a function call with JSON inside?

Comment: You'll need test the response string, ideally with a JS parser like esprima or acorn.

Answer (score 0):

You must use sinon and stub the handleThis function.